# looping for jquery load and wait until finished

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-load

I want to make a script that implement jquery to process php script that need a lot of execution time, so I split the process with jquery callback variable to process partially

but i don't know how to implement it. need help!

```
$("button").click(function(){
    i = 0;
    $("#div1").load("demo.php?i=" + i,function(){
        // when finished do jquery load "demo.php" again with i++ until i = 5
        i++;
    });
});
```

how to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would recommend using recursion and a callback function:

```
$("button").click(function(){
    load(0);
});

function load(i){
    if(i < 6){
        $("#div1").load("demo.php?i=" + i,function(){
            load(++i);
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22332895 ? because now append does't works again after I manually fill something in textarea. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
var i=0;
function loadQuery(){
    if(i<5)
    {
      $("#div1").load("demo.php?i="+i,function(){
      i++;
      loadQuery();
       });
    }

 }

 $("button").click(function(){loadQuery();}
```

Comment: defining `i` global will allow `loadQuery()` to be used only once if not re-initiliazed to 0