# jQuery append function doesn't work again after I made a change on textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-append

I have 1 button

```
<input type="button" id="scrape-button" value="Scrape" />
<textarea id="result" name="result"></textarea>
<textarea id="temp" name="temp" style="display: none;"></textarea>
```

When I click scrape button first it works

But when I fill something manually on textarea then click scrape button again, `$("#result").append($("#temp").val())` function doesn't work again. why?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#scrape-button").click(function(){
        var i = 0;
        var start = $("#start").val();
        var num = $("#num").val();
        var pages = $("#pages").val();
        $("#result").val("");
        load(i, pages, start, num);
    });
    function load(i, pages, start, num) {
        if (i < pages){
            url = $("#category").val() + $("#collection").val();
            $("#url").text("h" + url);
            $("#temp").load("coba.php?url=" + encodeURIComponent(url) + "&start=" + start + "&num=" + num, function(){
                if ($("#result").val() != '') $("#result").append("\n");
                $("#result").append($("#temp").val());
                start = parseInt(start) + parseInt(num);
                i++;
                $("#current").text(i + " / " + pages);
                load(i, pages, start, num);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

How to make it works?

Thanks before

Comment: What is in `$("#result").val()` when you first click the shuffle-button?

Comment: I made a change of question to specific the problem. thanks

Comment: usually console will tell you the error

Comment: I figure it only $("#result").append($("#temp").val()) function doesn't works again after I manually fill something in textarea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The use of `append` on `$("#result")` will not append to the value of the `textarea` like you may expect - for that you need to use the `val()` function.

So instead, to overwrite all the contents of the `textarea`, use:

```
$("#result").val($("#temp").val());
```

To append to the contents of the `textarea`, use something similar to:

```
var $result = $("#result"); 
$result.val($result.val() + $("#temp").val());
```